# how to write "IF" formula for below mention query

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a query

```
Column   A      B
       <=150    ±2
       151~300  ±3
       >=301    ±4
```

How to use "IF" formula for this

Answer (score 2):

Simply check if the value is between the lower and upper boundary. Lots of documentation available if you google for "excel between values".

```
=AND(val>301-4,val<301+4)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [Kadetje's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49506872/9290986) would be to use the `Abs` function and find the difference:

```
=ABS(A1-301)<=4
```

(Because `A1=301±4` can also be written as `A1-301=±4` or `±(A1-301)=4`, which is the same as `|A1-301|=4`.  To include numbers between the extremes (instead of just 297 and 305), just change `=` to `≤` and you wind up with `|A1-301|≤4` - finish up by converting that to Excel)